# The admin toolbar is messing up the sticky position set with fundation

Tags: toolbar

i am using the sticky component from foundation to render a sidebar element sticky.
It does work when unconnected but when connected the toolbar cover the sticky element.
How could i fix this ?

[fundation sticky component](https://get.foundation/sites/docs/sticky.html)

```
<div data-sticky class='toc-desktop toc toc-tree sticky' data-top-anchor="main:top" data-btm-anchor="footer:bottom">
<div>a table of content</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i used then the fundation data-margin-top attribute

```
<div id='toc-desktop' data-sticky class='toc-desktop toc toc-tree sticky' data-top-anchor="main:top" data-btm-anchor="main:bottom" data-margin-top="5">
```